# Local and production database column names dont match (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to group my posts by a date string and within that group I want to sort them by name. The date column is called **releaseDate** and the name is called **releaseName**.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
   def index
      @upcoming_releases = UpcomingRelease.all(:order => 'releaseDate, releaseName')
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.json { render json: @upcoming_releases }
      end
   end
```

That works fine in my local app but once I deploy to Heroku I get this error:

```
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801562+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "upcoming_releases".* FROM "upcoming_releases"   ORDER BY releaseDate, releaseName):
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801562+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801336+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "releasedate" does not exist
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801562+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801336+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "upcoming_releases".* FROM "upcoming_releases"   ORDER BY releaseDate, releaseName):
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801336+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801336+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "releasedate" does not exist
2014-01-17T00:21:54.801562+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/upcoming_releases_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I tried changing **releaseDate** to **release_date** but it doesn't work. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little research on pg column case sensitivity led me to this url https://drupal.org/node/1622982.  It seems that in order for pg to stop changing the column names to lower case, you need to wrap it in quotes.  Try

```
UpcomingRelease.all(:order => '"releaseDate", "releaseName"')
```

I see this will become an issue specially if you're writing a lot of sql statements.  One solution is to follow rails convention and change the column name to use the underscore notation.  You can do that by creating a migration and adding the following

```
rename_column :upcoming_releases, :releaseDate, :release_date
```

Another issue is make sure that you're using pg as your local database so you most probably have the same setup as your production server.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm going to change my column names to match the rails convention and using pg as my local database.